# Data that updates other user controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I currently have two user controls that both utilize a list of objects. These lists of objects are coffee types. These 2 user controls show the coffee types in different ways.

What I want to do is, when a coffee type is selected in one user control, it will update or highlight the same coffee type selected in the other user control.

I tried making an `ObservableCollection` that both user controls would look at, but it did not work out.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to bind SelectedValue from one of the lists to another?

Answer (score 0):

The droids you are looking for: [Selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx)

> You can set the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property to true to ensure that the item selected always corresponds to the CurrentItem property in the ItemCollection. For example, suppose that there are two ListBox controls with their ItemsSource property set to the same source. Set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to true on both list boxes to ensure that the selected item in each ListBox is the same.

Comment: err... to understand what H.B. is talking about, you need to check first [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) - scroll to the bottom of MSDN page for example.

Comment: @DK: Not really, one does not need to concern oneself with CollectionViews for this because every collection has a default View which is generated automatically.

Comment: ah, good to know H.B., thanks - this is a very interesting topic to explore.

Comment: Hi guys, I still don't quite get this. 

But perhaps I will clarify a bit more. These 2 user controls, each have a dependency property that will hold the list (an observable collection), and when it is rendered it reads this list and updates the UI's of each one.

So now, in one user control, when i select a coffee type, it renders it in whatever manner, and i know what is clicked. But passing that to another user control, this can be done with Selector?

Comment: @Angelus: Try to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on both list-controls inside the two usercontrols (possibly make the UserControl itself forward this proeprty from the internal control)

Comment: Hi H.B. I do not see this property with Observablecollection?

Comment: @Angelus, it's not a property of ObservableCollection, it's something selection controls have, ListBoxes, ListViews & ComboBoxes. Selection does and should not concern the collection itself.

Comment: Hmmm. Would it be easier then if i had some sort of variable in both user controls, such that, they were linked somehow, and if the variable changed in one control, it would change in the other?

Comment: @Angelus: I doubt it, i assume you have two list-controls in the usercontrols, just propagate that property if you do not want to hardcode it internally.